# How to set an attribute value by Javascript expression while building the HTML through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have something:

```
<div data-value="value == 1 || value == 3">
```

this won't return with the evaluated value, not even with `eval()`. The value is in a foreach value, a Javascript value. I cant use `.attr` with jQuery because the HTML is being built right now

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't assign the values (or other attributes) *after* the DOM has been built?

Comment: How are you building the HTML?

Comment: @DavidThomas and how to do it?

Comment: Can we not assign the values after the DOM loaded? Also, core JS setAttribute() function is also useful...

Comment: Need to know a bit more... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That would depend entirely on what you're trying to do, and to what end. What value are you trying to set as a result of what test?

Comment: Im building divs in a foreach loop. So <div data-value="x"> and I should put <script>$('body').last().attr('data-value', value == 1 || value == 3);</script> ? because that aint no work

Comment: `data-*` are strings, put quotes around : `value == 1 || value == 3` Although it looks pretty useless...

Comment: I think the problem is more likely to be one of logic, rather than syntax...
What you have here will work in as much as you are setting an attribute value to a string. Why would you need to evaluate that further if it is being created from a loop?
If you need to evaluate an expression, give the div a single value that 'represents' the options you wish to evaluate...

Answer (score 0):

If you're injecting HTML using jQuery, you can extract the logic from the actual DOM element string and then input the final value.

```
var value = 1; // just for example sake
var condition = (value == 1 || value == 3);
$('body').last().attr('data-value', condition);
```

I'm assuming you're looking for a `true` or `false` check, according to the code you posted.